# how to understand this XCODE crash log

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, crash

My game in the appstore crashes from time to time. I get these crash reports from the Crashes Organizer. They are partially symbolicated. The problem is that the part where it's not symbolicated is the part I need to understand the most. How can I make sense of the address (0x100054000) in this crash log?

[image: Crash log]

Comment: Is ZvH your application?

Comment: This can be understood as follows. In your `update(_:)` method of one of your `SKScene`, you are accessing an index of `NSMutableArray` that is probably out of bounds. That's why you are getting this exception. Please check your `update(_:)` method once in all of your `SKScene` if possible. Please let me know what you found.

Comment: I agree with KrishnaCA probably you have an `NSRangeException` inside the `update` method or in a method called from the `update` method

Comment: Put an exception break point and see the line where app has crashed.

Comment: @shallowThought yes it's ZvH

Comment: @KrishnaCA I already kew that it's an index out of bounds issue and it's somewhere in my update method because everything that happens in my game are inside the update method. The problem is that there are too many things happening in the update method and they're all inside 100's of classes. In other words, my main SKScene method calls the update method of the Enemy class, the projectile class, the towers class, hero class, etc. And what makes it difficult to debug is it doesn't happen all the time. It happens very rarely. Our testers sometimes crash, but I never crash while playing it.

Comment: @Whirlwind The problem is that the crash does not happen all the time. I've played my game countless of times while debugging and it never crashed. But in production it has crashed 5 times in 2 weeks with that same out of range exception. Is there a way somehow to symbolicate that address?

Comment: @JamesM, wherever you are using `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`, I believe you can put a check like `if (index < array.length) { //access the array};` to avoid crashes like this

Comment: @JamesM I see. Well, you can add some check as pointed above. Also you can check this out : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

Comment: Any news? I've the same issue.